# How can I get menus with icons in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, icons, menu, user-interface

I try to set icons for programs and context menus by dconf under org>gnome>desktop>interface>menus-have-icons but didn't work, help!

Expected results:

[image: menus-have-icons]

(in Freya I think I got this using Ubuntu-Tweak)

Comment: Need more information here. What kind of menus with what kinds of icons? Try searching for "elementary-tweaks" on GitHub, if that's what you used before

Comment: @wolf the icons in the program and context menus, I added a image as a reference.

Comment: I would be interested in hearing from the Elementary Designers why is this not included by default.

Comment: Which menus are you expecting to have icons that do not? I'm trying to determine whether the `menus-have-icons` toggle is working as expected

Comment: @wolf Inkscape, Firefox, Nemo... but don't worry, I find why `menus-have-icons` didn't work and a workaround [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23116/how-to-fix-missing-icons-in-program-menus-and-context-menus/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full explanation [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23116/how-to-fix-missing-icons-in-program-menus-and-context-menus/).

What concern us: setting this via `org.gnome.desktop.interface` does not work because `menus-have-icons` (and `buttons-have-icons`) is deprecated, but it's still possible to set this parameter by adding: `, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>` to **"overrides"** key in `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings` (with a comma and a space before, because in eOS this key is not empty)

[image]

and voilà:

[image: happy icons in nemo's context menu]

Comment: the file manager is PCManFM isn't it? - This doesn't work in Pantheon Files, does it?

Comment: this doesn't affect Pantheon Files: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10147/170  -- Wishlist/bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1542709

Comment: It's Nemo, @cipricus, [the WebUpd8 fork](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/11/nemo-320-with-unity-patches-and-without.html)